# Proton rocket's engine fizzle

Tags: engines, proton-m

Why does one of Proton's engines sometimes leave a dark gas?

[image: Credit:Rocosmos]

Is it some sort of byproduct of the UDMH and NTO reaction or did the engine fail?

Comment: interesting question. Proton's RD 253 engines are closed cycle and run oxidized-rich, so the plume would not be "the usual suspect", turbine exhaust

Comment: What is the source of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proton M uses UDMH as fuel and dinitrogen tetroxide as oxidizer. Should anything go seriously wrong it is entirely possible for dinitrogen tetroxide to leak and it is not a stable substance in the atmosphere. It will decompose to nitrogen dioxide which is dark brown in colour. As can be seen here: